# Recursion Printing Balanced Parantheses

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, printing, output

I have a recursion function which prints all the valid combinations of balanced parentheses as follows :

```
function addParen(upstock, downstock, sa)
{
    if (upstock == 0 && downstock == 0)
    {
        Print(sa);
    }

    if (upstock > 0)
    {
        addParen(upstock - 1, downstock + 1, sa + "(");
    }

    if (downstock > 0)
    {
        addParen(upstock, downstock - 1, sa + ")");
    }
}
```

It directly prints the result as strings like "((()))" or "()()()" for n=3 ( we assume 3 pairs, number of pairs is not important). However I want my recursive function to print one by one each parenthesis whenever the initial empty string concatenated with a "(" or ")".For instance for the first combination I want it to print like "("  then "(" then "(" then ")" then ")" and then ")".Then it can proceed with the same way for the second combination.Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: do you want to wait for an user input? is that what you are asking? the function is correct, or what are you trying to do is "(" "(" "(" ")" ")" ")"

Comment: No, what I want to do is while the recursion is going on and the string is concatenated with a left or right parenthesis, I immediately want to put that parenthesis on the screen. With that function, I always put the completed string on the screen whenever the upstock and the downstock is equal to zero.

Comment: How do you expect it to print the second string with a given prefix?  Or are you looking for a tree-style output?

Comment: The reason I ask this when the input is too large I want to see the resulting combinations on the screen while the program is doing the rest of it.

Comment: But your program prints each string out when it finds it; it doesn't need to wait for all the strings to be computed. So what problem are you observing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yours is not working with the balanced parenthesis because you need to make another checks. Bellow I am putting the result with the total number of combinations.

```
function addParen(n, upstock, downstock, sa){
        var count = 0;

        if(sa.length == 2 * n  && upstock == downstock){
                console.log(sa);
                //number of valid combinations
                return 1;
            }

        if(upstock >= downstock && upstock <= n){
            count += addParen(n, upstock + 1, downstock, sa + "(");
        }

        if(downstock < upstock){
            count += addParen(n, upstock, downstock + 1, sa + ")");
        }

        return count;
    } 

function numberOfBalancedParenthesis(n){
    return addParen(n, 0, 0, "");
}

//try this on the console
numberOfBalancedParenthesis(2)
```

Comment: It still gets messy.Only prints the first combination valid.I also did this but could not succeed.

Comment: Thank you. It now works.It prints each element one by one right ? Not as a whole string.

Comment: actually is one by one, after it founds the correct string, but it goes for all existing combinations, if the answer worked for you, please mark it as solved

Comment: It works, I marked it as solved.Why I wanted to ask this ? Because when the input n is too large I want to start seeing the resulting combinations on the screen while the program still does the rest of the combinations.However I could not make it.

Comment: I think you are confusing the idea of what you want to resolve and the browser behavior. You want to see the combinations while the browser is computing the rest, but that is another question, on javascript there is not a sleep function, the closest thing is setting a timeout with this function setTimeout to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you're looking for!

```
function addParen( upstock, downstock ) {

      if (upstock > 0 )
      {
          Print("(");
          addParen(upstock - 1, downstock+1);
      }

      if (downstock > 0 )
      {
          Print(")");
          addParen(upstock, downstock - 1);
      }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not display all the results correctly.